# How to use Web API 2 with MVC4

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am looking for some solutions, is there any way to use web API 2 with MVC 4 I am working on MVC4 but i want to use Web API 2 in my application.

Comment: Your question is too generic.Please try to narrow it down.
Here is link to learn Wep API
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i am using visual studio 2010 (4.0) so i can not upgrade MVC4 to MVC5 because Visual studio 2010 does not support MVC5 but i want to use Web API2 how can i